# Oracle SQL Developer how to get a sum from the result of another query

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

I'm here presenting an issue that I'm having all day long.

There is my SQL query :

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182,'$.transactionDetails[*].transactionChannelId') as CHANNELTRANSACTION,
    RESP_REFERENCE0182 TRANSACTIONID,
    ACTION0182,
    JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount') MONTO
FROM
    POSTING_ONLINE0182 PO
INNER JOIN Z_MAMBU_TRANSACTIONS ZMT 
  ON PO.RESP_REFERENCE0182 = ZMT.TRANSACTIONID
WHERE
    POSTING_RESPCODE0182 = 0
    AND TO_CHAR(REPLACE(ZMT.AMOUNT, ',', '.')) = JSON_VALUE(PO.MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount')
GROUP BY    
    JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182,'$.transactionDetails[*].transactionChannelId'),
    RESP_REFERENCE0182,
    ACTION0182,
    JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount')
ORDER BY
    ACTION0182
```

Here is the result:

[image: 1]

So what I need is to get the sum of all the debits, and then all the credits and show them in 2 different rows. I tried with a lot of methods and things but its not working.

This is an example of what I need:

[image: 2]

Where it says MONTO i need sum of the previous valours in the first picture

Thanks! if someone can help me it would be so nice

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
select channeltransaction, action0182, sum(MONTO) MONTO
from (your query...)
group by channel_transaction, action0182;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this.  Your existing query is complicated enough that I'm leaving it alone (other than removing the `order by`) in a common table expression (CTE) called `your_query`.  You could have it be an inline view instead if you prefer

```
with your_query as (
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182,'$.transactionDetails[*].transactionChannelId') as CHANNELTRANSACTION,
    RESP_REFERENCE0182 TRANSACTIONID,
    ACTION0182,
    JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount') MONTO
FROM
    POSTING_ONLINE0182 PO
    INNER JOIN Z_MAMBU_TRANSACTIONS ZMT ON PO.RESP_REFERENCE0182 = ZMT.TRANSACTIONID
WHERE
    POSTING_RESPCODE0182 = 0
    AND TO_CHAR(REPLACE(ZMT.AMOUNT, ',', '.')) = JSON_VALUE(PO.MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount')
GROUP BY
    JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182,'$.transactionDetails[*].transactionChannelId'),
    RESP_REFERENCE0182,
    ACTION0182,
    JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount')
)
select CHANNELTRANSACTION,
       ACTION0182,
       sum(monto)
  from your_query
 group by CHANNELTRANSACTION,
          ACTION0182
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! im not getting the "with your_query as" that u are saying, what i need to put there?

Comment: @Owunn - That's literally the syntax.  I just aliased the query you posted as `your_query` in the CTE.

Comment: Nice thank you :)! i did it but im getting a "invalid number" i think it can be because the JSON_VALUE(MSGTOSEND_0182, '$.amount') is a string?

Comment: @Owunn - Can some of the values not be converted to numbers using your session's NLS settings?  That's what the error implies.  Are there non-numeric values?  Does your session use the comma as the decimal separator rather than the period?